# Combine Dataframes based on specific iiteration number from dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2, where I would like to combine them based on iteration number from two columns

```
df1 =
    iteration   IOPS    Latency
0   1_1 46090   0.7300
1   2_2 12  0.0221
2   3_3 49164   0.1236
3   4_4 98311   0.1318
4   5_5 196604  0.2076
5   6_6 249843  0.1467
6   7_7 298974  0.1578
7   8_8 348108  0.1604
8   9_9 397230  0.1707


df2 = 
    iteration   IOPS    Latency
0   1_1 46074   0.6977
1   2_2 12  0.0279
2   3_3 49159   0.1921
3   4_4 98307   0.2189
4   5_5 298976  0.2337
5   6_6 397265  0.2622
```

I need to combine iteration 1_1,2_2,3_3,9_9 from df1 and 1_1,2_2,5_5,6_6

```
df3 = 
iteration  IOPS Latency iteration IOPS Latency
1_1  46090   0.7300    1_1 46074   0.6977
2_2     12   0.0221    2_2 12  0.0279
3_3  49164   0.1236    5_5 298976  0.2337
9_9  397230   0.1707   6_6 397265  0.2622
```

Comment: It would be nice to explicit the expected logic. I'm assuming you want to map the iteration numbers one to one in order. (`1_1` and `1_1`, `2_2` and `2_2`, `3_3` and `5_5`, `9_9` and `6_6`). Are those always sorted in the input dataframes? What happens if not? Can you have more than two input DataFrames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can align the DataFrames based on your lists of iteration ID, then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
def align(df, lst):
    return (df.set_index('iteration')
              .reindex(lst)
              .reset_index()
            )

out = pd.concat([align(df1, ['1_1', '2_2', '3_3', '9_9']),
                 align(df2, ['1_1', '2_2', '5_5', '6_6']),
                ], axis=1)
```

If you have more than two DataFrames, a more generic options using [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
from itertools import starmap

dfs = [df1, df2]
iters = [['1_1', '2_2', '3_3', '9_9'],
         ['1_1', '2_2', '5_5', '6_6'],
        ]

def align(df, lst):
    return (df.set_index('iteration')
              .reindex(lst)
              .reset_index()
            )

out = pd.concat(starmap(align, zip(dfs, iters)), axis=1)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
  iteration    IOPS  Latency iteration    IOPS  Latency
0       1_1   46090   0.7300       1_1   46074   0.6977
1       2_2      12   0.0221       2_2      12   0.0279
2       3_3   49164   0.1236       5_5  298976   0.2337
3       9_9  397230   0.1707       6_6  397265   0.2622
```

Comment: Good point about `isin`; safer to reindex. In that case, only adding the advice for the OP that duplicate column labels are best avoided. Instead of `pd.concat`, using `pd.merge(*dfs, left_index=True, right_index=True)` (where `dfs` is a list) would add clarifying suffixes. With more than 2 dfs, I suppose one could wrap things in a `enumerate` and use `pd.add_suffix` per `df`.

Comment: @ouroboros1 yes, that's a good point. In this case I'd probably use a MultiIndex: `out = pd.concat(dict(enumerate(starmap(align, zip(dfs, iters)), start=1)), axis=1)`. For a suffix: `out = pd.concat((d.add_suffix(i) for i, d in enumerate(starmap(align, zip(dfs, iters)), start=1)), axis=1)`